# Configure Windows PowerShell to display only the current folder name in the shell prompt

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I'm using PowerShell on Windows 7. How can I configure PowerShell so that it only displays the current folder name (instead of the full path) in the shell prompt?

For example, instead of `C:\folder\directory\name>`, I want `name>`.

Comment: If you want the prompt with a path relative to your home directory, this worked for me: `function prompt { "[$((''+$PWD).replace($HOME, '~'))]> " }`

Comment: The question has already been answered, but I created a shortened Prompt for Poweshell that includes a bit more information. Has shortened names for some common directories (limited atm, may include more) and shortens home drive to "\": https://gist.github.com/1nVitr0/486b238a1e9a361dd0a2f6fc92f86d4f.

Example: "$ ~\Drv\Docs\pers\proj\vsc\exts\daily-timelog >"

Maybe it'll help somebody

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You have to customize the prompt function in your PowerShell profile (`%userprofile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`); it may be blank or even not exist if you have never modified it before.

1. Open your profile (e.g., open the aforementioned file or while in PowerShell, `Notepad $profile`)
2. Add the following to your profile:

   ```
   function prompt {
     $p = Split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location)
     "$p> "
   }
   ```
3. Save the profile
4. Restart PowerShell

   **Optional**. If you get a message that says you are not allowed to run scripts, then you need to copy/paste this line in PowerShell:

   ```
   Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
   ```

   and restart.

> Windows PowerShell execution policies let you determine the conditions under which Windows PowerShell loads configuration files and runs scripts.
>
> You can set an execution policy for the local computer, for the current user, or for a particular session. You can also use a Group Policy setting to set execution policy for computers and users.
>
> Source: [Microsoft Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core)

Comment: Not quite right. `[System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()` does not represent powershell's current location, but rather the process working directory, which are not always the same. Replace with `Get-Location`

Comment: +1, but I would use get-location instead of `GetCurrentDirectory`. Remember that PowerShell does not always mean the file system. Using the registry snap-in, I could use `cd hkcu:` and now the prompt would be totally off.

Comment: @Synetech It's [buried quite deep](http://superuser.com/editing-help#advanced-lists) in the formatting help :\

Comment: You can also use `$PWD` instead of calling `Get-Location`. E.g. `function prompt { (Split-Path -Leaf $pwd) + '> ' }`

Comment: You don't have to define `prompt` in your profile file. It just has to be in the global session scope. The default seems equivalent to `function prompt {"PS " + (Get-Location) + ">"}`, while `function prompt {""}` gives the same as `function prompt {"PS>"}`. Use ``function prompt {" `b"}`` to get an empty prompt (at least visually...).

Comment: To add to this. Like me, if you also want your conda environment to show up before the name of the directory, then change the prompt line to `"$env:CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER$p> "`

Answer (score 17):

Change the prompt to show current folder without full path and greater than symbol at the end:

One way could be:

```
Function Prompt { "$( ( get-item $pwd ).Name )>" }
```

Or:

```
Function Prompt { "$( Split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location) )>" }
```

Or:

```
Function Prompt { "$( ( Get-Location | Get-Item ).Name )>" }
```

Comment: The first and third are better than the accepted answer in that they work for network folders. Split-Path won't function correctly on a path like `\\myserver\my\path`.

Comment: And if I wanted to go back to before? How can I revert these?

Comment: It depends on what you had before. If you want to show the path and then the "greater than" symbol, use something like this:

Function Prompt { "$pwd>" }

Answer (score 11):

As an additional note, I couldn't do [Synetech's command](https://superuser.com/questions/446827/configure-windows-powershell-to-display-only-the-current-folder-name-in-the-shel/446836#446836) until I first created the $profile.

1. Open PowerShell
2. Type `$profile` and hit enter. This will display the profile path PowerShell relies on, even if it doesn't exist (it didn't for me). My path was different than [what Synetech posted](https://superuser.com/questions/446827/configure-windows-powershell-to-display-only-the-current-folder-name-in-the-shel/446836#446836).

   ```
    >$profile
    C:\Users\[username]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
   ```
3. I had to create both the *WindowsPowerShell* folder and the *Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1* file.
4. Add [Synetech's code](https://superuser.com/questions/446827/configure-windows-powershell-to-display-only-the-current-folder-name-in-the-shel/446836#446836) and restart PowerShell.

Note:

If you're using posh-git (which is installed when using GitHub desktop), [Synetech's script](https://superuser.com/questions/446827/configure-windows-powershell-to-display-only-the-current-folder-name-in-the-shel/446836#446836) will override the posh-git prompt. Additional prompt scripts for posh-git [here](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/wiki/Customizing-Your-PowerShell-Prompt).

Comment: It's the same. `%userprofile%` expands to `C:\Users\[username]`

Comment: @DavidPostill that was my understanding, but my PowerShell didn't recognize %userprofile% as a directory. I don't believe my PowerShell is customized yet to recognize those paths, perhaps due to network settings?

Comment: The syntax is different in PowerShell: `$Env:userprofile` is equivalent to `echo %userprofile%`

Comment: $profile has a different value in ISE vs. the regular prompt, you may have to create 2 files.

Answer (score 5):

I found this was pretty easy - combining [Synetech's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/446827/configure-windows-powershell-to-display-only-the-current-folder-name-in-the-shel/446836#446836) and the information found at [PowerShell profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(v=vs.85).aspx). Because I am a newbie to PowerShell. My steps (for Visual Studio Code):

1. `test-path $profile` (in the PowerShell command prompt - is there a profile set up?)
2. `new-item -path $profile -itemtype file -force` (assuming the answer to the above is false)
3. `notepad $profile` (opens Notepad)
4. Paste in

   ```
    function prompt {
      $p = Split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location)
      "$p> "
    }
   ```
5. Save (you shouldn't have to chose a location; it is already done for you)
6. Reload Visual Studio Code - you will probably get a message about running scripts (or just do next step before reload)
7. `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser` (at your PowerShell prompt, from the Super User answer)
8. Reload Visual Studio Code

So it is mostly Synetech's answer with a bit to get started easily - especially step 2 makes this very easy.

Comment: Very easy steps to follow

Answer (score 3):

I wanted a more elaborate prompt and constructed a new prompt. This answer is not meant to replace the current answer, but more as an addition for those who stumble upon this later. This prompt will have full support over network paths and looks very elegant.

```
function Prompt
{
    write-host "PS " -ForegroundColor Magenta -NoNewline
    write-host (get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
    write-host " | " -ForegroundColor DarkGray -NoNewline
    write-host "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME " -NoNewline
    write-host " | " -ForegroundColor DarkGray -NoNewline
    if( (Get-Location).Drive -ne $null)
    {
        write-host (Get-Location) 
        $networkdrive = $false
    }
    else
    {
        $networkdrive = $true
        $first, $second, $third, $folder = (Get-Location).path.Split("\")
        write-host "\" -NoNewline
        $folder | foreach-object {
            write-host "\$_" -NoNewline
        }
        write-host
    }
    write-host "PS " -ForegroundColor Magenta -NoNewline
    if( (Get-Location).Drive -ne $null)
    {
        write-host "$((Get-Location).Drive):\"  -NoNewline
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "\\$((Get-Location).path.Split("\")[3])\"  -NoNewline
    }

    if( (Get-Location).path.Split("\").Count -gt 2 -and $networkdrive -eq $false)
    {
        write-host "…\"  -NoNewline
    }
    if( (Get-Location).path.Split("\").Count -gt 5 -and $networkdrive -eq $true)
    {
        write-host "…\"  -NoNewline
    }    write-host "$((Get-Location).path.Split("\")[-1])"  -NoNewline
    write-host ">" -NoNewline
    return " "
}
```

It will show a prompt like this:

```
PS 2021-03-24 02:03:39 | \\MYPC  | \\Server\Share\Folder1\Folder2
PS \\Server\…\Folder2> cd c:\Users\User
PS 2021-03-24 02:03:39 | \\MYPC  | C:\Users\User
PS C:\…\User>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below single line works fine for me:

```
(Get-Location | Get-Item).Name
```

Comment: that wasn't the question - see above correct answer from Jelgab

Comment: This is a good way for one instance via powershell prompt

Answer (score 1):

For posh-git the best way I've found is to customize the `$GitPromptSettings.DefaultPromptPath.Text` [property](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/wiki/Customizing-Your-PowerShell-Prompt#v1x---customizing-the-posh-git-prompt).

In the profile:

```
    $GitPromptSettings.DefaultPromptPath.Text = '$(Split-Path -leaf -path ($ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation))'
```

Results in this (can't embed images yet, seemingly):

[posh-git prompt showing only current directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dDFd.png)

Answer (score 1):

I created this neat prompt to that shows the drive and last folder.

For you example it would render as

```
PS C:\Users\b.HQ\Desktop\tsdev\my_folder>
```

as

```
PS C:\...\my_folder>
```

The prompt function is:

```
function prompt {"PS " + (get-location).drive.name+":\...\"+ $( ( get-item $pwd ).Name ) +">"}
```

Comment: copy/paste/execute and go on with life, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anaconda then you probably want to change your profile function to

```
function Prompt {
    $p = Split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location)
    "$env:CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER $p> "
}
```

Although I think that just splitting on the last path component is a bit too much. The problem that I'm trying to solve is paths that take up an entire line (actually quite common in a codebase)

```
function Prompt {
    $maxLength = 50
    $p = (Get-Location).Path
    if ($p.Length -gt $maxLength) {
        $s = Split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location)
        if ($s.Length -gt $maxLength - 1) {
            $p = $s
        }
        else {
            $p = "...$($p.Substring($p.Length - $maxLength + 3))"
        }
    }

    "$env:CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER $p> "
}
```

You can ditch the `$env:CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER` if you don't use Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

I write a function that provides three styles {`None`, `Name`, `Fulllpath`} so you can easily change the prompt anytime.

```
<#
.Description
    It can simplify the prompt, so if your path is too long still okay.
    Implement: You are only to modify the "Prompt" function then done.
.Parameter style
    You can use tab to select the style.

    - None: do not show any text except ">" (this is default options)
    - Name: show the basename only
    - Fullpath: show the full path
.Outputs
    The output type is "string" so you must use "Invoke-Expression" to make it effective.
.Example
    Set-Prompt | iex
    Set-Prompt | Invoke-Expression
.Example
    Set-Prompt -style Name | iex
    Set-Prompt -style Fullpath | iex
.Example
    Set-Prompt -Verbose
#>
function Set-Prompt {
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateSet('None', 'Name', 'Fullpath')]
        [string]$style = "None"
    )

    [string]$myPromptFunc = ""

    switch ($style) {
        "None" {
            $myPromptFunc = 'function Prompt { ">" }'
        }
        "Name" {
            $myPromptFunc = @"
    function Prompt {
        "`$((Get-Item `$pwd).Name)>"
    }
"@
        }
        "Fullpath" {
            $myPromptFunc = 'function Prompt { Write-Output "$($pwd.Path)>" }'
        }
    }

    if ($VerbosePreference -eq "Continue") {
        Write-Host "Call " -NoNewLine
        Write-Host 'Set-Prompt | Invoke-Expression' -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewLine
        Write-Host " to apply."

        Write-Host "The prompt function will be changed as follow" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    Write-Output $myPromptFunc
}
```

demo

```
# Example1 default: None
PS C:\Windows\System32> Set-Prompt | iex
>

# Example1 Name
PS C:\Windows\System32> Set-Prompt -style Name | iex
System32>cd ..
Windows>

# Example3 fullpath
PS C:\Windows\System32> Set-Prompt -style Fullpath | iex
C:\Windows\System32>cd ..
C:\Windows>
```

---

You don't have to copy-paste every time.
You can create a source directory <sup>try to search `psd1`, `psm1`</sup> and then add the path to `PSModulePath`, and you can use it directly next time.

> for powershell5, you may need to `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -F` before you use the command.
>
> For PowerShell 7, you can use it directly.