# On the Windows commandline, how do I get a dynamic prompt that tells me where in the filesystem I am?

Tags: windows, command-line, prompt, cmd.exe

I am trying to modify my CMD, to show only the current directory name dynamically, like:

```
Desktop $
```

When I switch the folder, it must be updated.

It is not required to be code in a **pure** batch file. It may depend on any external commands, [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) Bash, etc.

```
@echo off
set a=bash -c "pwd | sed 's,^\(.*/\)\?\([^/]*\),\2,'"
%a%
cmd
```

Outputs

```
_test-et
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. Tüm hakları saklıdır.
>>
```

But

```
>> prompt %a%
```

gives

```
bash -c "pwd | sed 's,^\(.*/\)\?\([^/]*\),\2,'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Microsoft's PowerShell, the prompt is produced by a function that can do anything at all.

A prompt function that does what you want is:

```
function prompt { (Split-Path -Leaf $pwd) + '$ ' }
```

For more information, see:

- [Configure Windows PowerShell to display only the current folder name in the shell prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/446827/configure-the-windows-powershell-to-display-only-the-current-folder-name-in-the)
- [PowerShell about Prompts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts)
- [Perfect Prompt for Windows PowerShell](http://mshforfun.blogspot.fr/2006/05/perfect-prompt-for-windows-powershell.html)

Comment: It is time to switch off CMD age and switch to PowerShell :)
Thanks. Difficult to give up habituation but it is more likely cygwin, `cd ~` works on PowerShell, but not in cmd.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can use the **`prompt`** command.

```
PROMPT [text]

  text    Specifies a new command prompt.

Prompt can be made up of normal characters and the following special codes:

  $A   & (Ampersand)
  $B   | (pipe)
  $C   ( (Left parenthesis)
  $D   Current date
  $E   Escape code (ASCII code 27)
  $F   ) (Right parenthesis)
  $G   > (greater-than sign)
  $H   Backspace (erases previous character)
  $L   < (less-than sign)
  $N   Current drive
  $P   Current drive and path
  $Q   = (equal sign)
  $S     (space)
  $T   Current time
  $V   Windows version number
  $_   Carriage return and linefeed
  $$   $ (dollar sign)

If Command Extensions are enabled the PROMPT command supports
the following additional formatting characters:

  $+   zero or more plus sign (+) characters depending upon the
       depth of the PUSHD directory stack, one character for each
       level pushed.

  $M   Displays the remote name associated with the current drive
       letter or the empty string if current drive is not a network
       drive.
```

---

Example:

```
setx PROMPT $P$S$$$S
```

### Update

Create a batch file containing the code below and run.

```
@echo off

set root=%~p0
for %%F in ("%root%.") do set "ParentFolder=%%~nF"
setx PROMPT %ParentFolder%$S$F$S
```

Result is:

[image]

Comment: Can you see above `CURRENT DIRECTORY` variable? Let's test it. Open cmd, and set prompt to:

`set prompt=$B$C$D$E$F$G$H$L$N$P$Q$S$T$V$_$$`

which contains all variables except `$+ and $M`. 
But still I can not see still current dir, but give
`|(Pzt 04.11.2013←)<CC:\Users= 17:44:02,69Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]`

Why? Is there a huge bug on cmd.exe?

Comment: @guneysus I updated my answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks but i must change it, because current folder is not dynamic and with `setx` it is systemwide :) It shoud be `set` not `setx`

In addition i will try replace  `cd` function, to update it dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the wikipedia entry for [AUTOEXEC.BAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AUTOEXEC.BAT) `prompt $P$G` will do what you want.  This is a holdover from good old DOS.   God only knows why something like this was never made a default since the early days of ... DOS3.3 or so.

Comment: This is not what OP wants. It gives the complete path. OP wants only the last part of the current directory (without its parent-path). And it needs to change when changing the directory. It's not possible with the current `prompt` command. At least not in `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

I like knowing the full context of where I am in the console, but the deeper you go down the directory tree, the longer the "Current drive and path", so to have the best of both worlds, I have the full drive and path followed by a CR then a ">".

This is what I now do on all Windows machines I get access to:

```
SETX PROMPT "%username%@%computername% $P$_$G"
```

Which gives you a prompt showing the username, hostname, full path to the current folder, and a whole new line for typing:

```
USERNAME@HOSTNAME C:\PATH\TO\CURRENT\FOLDER
>
```

SETX stores the variable (in this case, "PROMPT") permanently (through reboots, until you change it).